# Basic Noughts & Crosses

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

So I got bored and made a simple noughts and crosses game with colours instead of symbols.

The colours are red and blue and I made the GUI in  NetBeans with my own code in combination with the NetBeans GUI Editor.

My Code:

```
package com.coal;

import java.util.Random;


public class Noughts extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public Noughts() {
    if (ran == 0) {
        move = "Red";
    } else {
        move = "Blue";
    }
    initComponents();

}

private void checkForVictory() {
    //Horizontal Victories
    if (color1 == 1 && color2 == 1 && color3 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color1 == 2 && color2 == 2 && color3 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    if (color4 == 1 && color5 == 1 && color6 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color4 == 2 && color5 == 2 && color6 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    if (color7 == 1 && color8 == 1 && color9 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color7 == 2 && color8 == 2 && color9 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    //Vertical Victories
    if (color1 == 1 && color4 == 1 && color7 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color1 == 2 && color4 == 2 && color7 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    if (color2 == 1 && color5 == 1 && color8 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color2 == 2 && color5 == 2 && color8 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    if (color3 == 1 && color6 == 1 && color9 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color3 == 2 && color6 == 2 && color9 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    //Diagonal Victories
    if (color1 == 1 && color5 == 1 && color9 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color1 == 2 && color5 == 2 && color9 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }

    if (color3 == 1 && color5 == 1 && color7 == 1) {
        winner = "Red";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    if (color3 == 2 && color5 == 2 && color7 == 2) {
        winner = "Blue";
        System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
        gameOver = true;
        jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
    }
    //Draw Check
    if(color1 != 0 && color2 != 0 && color3 != 0&& color4 != 0&& color5 != 0&& color6 != 0&& color7 != 0&& color8 != 0&& color9 != 0 && winner == ""){
        System.out.println("Draw!");
        gameOver = true;
         jTextPane1.setText("Draw!");
    }
}

//0 is Plain, 1 is Red, 2 is Blue.
public static int color1 = 0;
public static int color2 = 0;
public static int color3 = 0;
public static int color4 = 0;
public static int color5 = 0;
public static int color6 = 0;
public static int color7 = 0;
public static int color8 = 0;
public static int color9 = 0;

public static String move;
public static Random random = new Random();
int ran = random.nextInt(2);

public static boolean gameOver = false;
public static String winner = "";


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    b1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Noughts & Crosses ");
    setResizable(false);

    b1.setLabel("");
    b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b2.setLabel("");
    b2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b3.setLabel("");
    b3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b7.setLabel("");
    b7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b5.setLabel("");
    b5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b6.setLabel("");
    b6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b4.setLabel("");
    b4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b9.setLabel("");
    b9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b8.setLabel("");
    b8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextPane1.setEditable(false);
    jTextPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
    jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(b4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(b5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(b6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(b1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(b2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(b3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(b7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(b8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(b9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(b1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(b5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(b7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(b8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void b5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color5 == 0) {
            if (move.equals("Red")) {
                b5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color5 = 1;
            } else {
                b5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color5 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }

        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color9 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color9 = 1;
            } else {

                b9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color9 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color8 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color8 = 1;
            } else {

                b8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color8 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color1 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color1 = 1;
            } else {

                b1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color1 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color7 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color7 = 1;
            } else {

                b7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color7 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color2 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color2 = 1;
            } else {

                b2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color2 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color3 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color3 = 1;
            } else {

                b3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color3 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color6 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color6 = 1;
            } else {

                b6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color6 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

private void b4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (!gameOver) {
        if (color4 == 0) {

            if (move.equals("Red")) {

                b4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
                move = "Blue";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);
                color4 = 1;
            } else {

                b4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                color4 = 2;
                move = "Red";
                jTextPane1.setText("Move: " + move);

            }
        }
        checkForVictory();
    }
}                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Noughts.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Noughts.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Noughts.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Noughts.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Noughts().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton b1;
private javax.swing.JButton b2;
private javax.swing.JButton b3;
private javax.swing.JButton b4;
private javax.swing.JButton b5;
private javax.swing.JButton b6;
private javax.swing.JButton b7;
private javax.swing.JButton b8;
private javax.swing.JButton b9;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I would just like to know if I could make any improvements or if I made it too long for too simple a program.

It functions but is the most basic of basic programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### remove code duplication

You have lots of duplicated code all over the program which could be reduced by the use of parameterized methods. E.g. the `checkForVictory()` method could be changed like this:

```
private void ckeckLine(int firstField, int middleField, int lastField, int playerColor, String playerName){
  if(firstField==playerColor&&middleField==playerColor&&lastField==playerColor){
       winner = playerName;
       System.out.println("Winner!" + winner);
       gameOver = true;
       jTextPane1.setText("Winner is " + winner);
  }
}


private void checkForVictoryForPlayer(int playerColor, String playerName ) {
    //Horizontal Victories
     ckeckLine(color1, color2, color3, playerColor ,playerName);
     ckeckLine(color4, color5, color6, playerColor ,playerName);
    // you get the idea?
}


private void checkForVictory(){
   checkForVictoryForPlayer(1, "Red");
   checkForVictoryForPlayer(2, "Blue");
   //Draw Check
   if(color1 != 0 && color2 != 0 && color3 != 0&& color4 != 0&& color5 != 0&& color6 != 0&& color7 != 0&& color8 != 0&& color9 != 0 && winner == ""){
      System.out.println("Draw!");
      gameOver = true;
       jTextPane1.setText("Draw!");
  }
}
```

Same is true for your `b?actionPerformed()` methods. There could be only one parameterized version instead of 9.